# Conditional rendering a button value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a game in which the initial state of the cards is face down, upon clicking a single card, the card's icon is revealed. When two cards match, both cards are removed from the board.
The challenge I'm having is in my conditional rendering. When I click on one card, all cards reveal their icon, not just one per click. Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/oq3113vnlz)

I'm trying to keep state as local as possible the the relevant components and also trying the do it the "React" way by not toggling classnames and directly manipulating the DOM. How can I fix this and is the btnMask class the right way to go? If I can get this, then matching id's on cards may be a quick implementation. Here is the Card class

```
class Card extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hidden: true
    };
    this.revealIcon = this.revealIcon.bind(this);
  }

 revealIcon(e) {
    console.log("clicked", e.target.id);
    this.setState({ hidden: false });
  }

  render() {
    const card = this.props.cardsEasy["cards"].map((card, index) => {
      if (this.state.hidden) {
        return (
         <button
            key={card + index}
            style={btn}
            onClick={this.revealIcon}
            id={card}
          >
            <div style={btnMask}>{card}</div>
          </button>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <button
            key={card + index}
            style={btn}
            onClick={this.revealIcon}
            id={card}
          >
            <div>{card}</div>
          </button>
        );
      }
    });
    return <div style={divContainer}>{card}</div>;
  }
}
export default Card;
```

Comment: your `<Card />` component renders all the cards. perhaps you try to map over `cardsEasy["cards"]` outside of this component and than any `<Card />` will have his own hidden state.

Comment: @DoronBrikman approach looks right. If you have a CardComponent separate you can handle its own state as visible or not.

Comment: So with @DoronBrikman, I'll turn my existing Card component into more of a container element to pass props though to the child component 'CardCollection' that way the mapping is more individual to each card

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you have a common state for all cards. This means you have Card Component in which you render all the cards. The component has the state of `hidden` and renders a bunch of cards. Those cards access all the same variable in the state to check if they should hide. Therefore if you change that variable, all of then show up. What I would suggest you to do is to create a component "CardCollection" which renders the card.

```
  class CardCollection extends React.Component {
    render() {
      this.props.cardsEasy["cards"].map((item) => {
        <Card {...item} />
      })
    }
  }
```

Like this each CardComponent will have their own state. You will need to adjust your CardComponent a little bit.

Instead of using a class component / stateful component you could also use a statless component for the CardCollection, as the collection doesn't need any state and is only there to render the childrens.

```
  const CardCollection = (props) => {
    return this.props.cardsEasy["cards"].map((item) => {
      <Card {...item} />
    });
  }
```

Comment: So I'm passing the props from Game (parent component) to CardCollection and then through to Card?

Comment: Correct. You use CardCollection only to create a list of Cards. Each Card then has their own state because you create an instance of CardComponent for each Card. Hence their state is no more shared and only your desired card get's shown.

Comment: Ok I modified the components, yet the props in the Card are more nested?? [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oq3113vnlz)

Comment: Im also stuck, on how I split the array of buttons returned from the map function in the render method into individual Cards...<Card>{card}</Card>. And in the card component I'm passing props.children